# P5 Number vs number

Tags: javascript, p5.js

Got error code

> p5.js says: [sketch.js, line 194] rect() was expecting Number for the first parameter, received number instead. (http://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/rect)

How do I solve this, and what's the difference? I thought js doesn't care about data type.

```
  x = i * cos(noise(i, j, t + 1) / i) * 15;
  y = i * sin(noise(i, j, t + 1) / i) * 15;
  rect(
    x,
    y,
    (i + 2) * 8 * (noise(0, i, t) + 0.5),
    (i + 2) * 8 * (noise(1, i, t) + 0.5)
  );
```

parameter 1,2 has error, but parameter 3,4 does

Comment: That message is from the P5 "Friendly Error System". I don't know why the message is weird like that.

Comment: Can you share a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), preferably via the `[<>]` button. It might help us debug your issue.

Comment: If you can build a reproducing example, this error message seems worth reporting to p5 as a bug (regardless of the underlying cause, the message itself is incredibly unhelpful).

Comment: What are some example values for I, i and t , can you log it and add post